# VFP CHR(9) not outputting TAB as expected

Tags: visual-foxpro

I need to create a tab-delimited file from a cursor. I would normally just use COPY TO but in this case I need to a header row which COPY TO doesn't create.

I thought I could use ?|?? along with CHR(9) but it doesn't put a TAB in the file. I opened the file with notepad++ and word with show special characters turned on. I expected to see the right-arrow for TAB but not there. The file looked more like a fixed width format

Here's my code

```
LOCAL lcWBSIncFile, lcEACIncHeader
lcEACIncHeader = "EarnedValue" + CRLF +;
    "ContrName" + CHR(9) + ;
    "StruName" + CHR(9) + ;
    "WbsNum" + CHR(9) + ;
    "EndDate" + CHR(9) + ;
    "UnitName" + CHR(9) + ;
    "UnitScale" + CHR(9) + ;
    "LRE"

lcWBSIncFile = RTRIM(vpcProgram) + "_" + dtoc(vpdStatusDate,1) + "_" + TTOC(DATETIME(),1) + "_WBS_EAC.inc"

SET ALTERNATE TO ( lcWBSIncFile )
SET ALTER ON
SET CONSOLE OFF

? lcEACIncHeader
SELECT _csrEACUpdateWBSFinal
SCAN
    ? contrname + CHR(9)
    ?? struname + CHR(9)
    ?? wbsnum+ CHR(9)
    ?? enddate + CHR(9)
    ?? unitname + CHR(9)
    ?? unitscale + CHR(9)
    ?? ALLT(STR(lre,24,2 ))
ENDSCAN
SET ALTERNATE TO
SET ALTERNATE OFF
```

COPY TO (filename) TYPE DELIMITED WITH TAB works fine, I just don't get a header.

Comment: Maybe use COPY TO and then use FileToString() and StrToFile() to add the header at the top?

Comment: Hi Tamar, I did think of that but I tried FPUTS() first and that worked. Not sure why FPUTS and ? work differently

Comment: ? does some formatting as it goes. It's really not for carefully formatted output.

Answer (score 0):

? | ?? didn't work but FPUTS() did. Not sure why.